# Keep specific tensor row chunks in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, split, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow 1.0.1 in python 3.x.

I have a tensor `L` that has `n x seq` rows, and I want to keep the first `i` elements per `seq` rows, for `i` in `c`. So `len(c)=n`, and  the `i-th` element in `c` denotes how many elements to keep in the `i-th` `seq`-sized partition of `L`, starting from that partition's beginning.

For example, if `L=list(range(10))` and `c=[2,4]` then the desired result is `D=[0,1,5,6,7,8]`. Of course, in the real example, `L` and `D` are `? x dim` tensors.

I tried to use [`tf.split(T,c,0)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split), where I computed the number of items to be discarded in each seq, getting`c=[2,3,4,1]` as per the example. Having that, the desired rows would be the elements of the `tf.split` result list, after discarding every other element.

Problem is, the values and length of `c` are fed through a placeholder and are  unknown during graph creation, so I get an exception:

```
ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape Tensor("tensorname", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```

The doc of the tf.split() says that it throws the exception above if the number of splits `num` cannot be inferred from the `num_or_size_splits` arg. So the number of splits absolutely *has to* be known at graph construction time?

If so, can you think of a statically definable way to achieve the goal below or a workaround?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we can use [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) and [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) to get specific indices out of tensors.

So to get the desired positions, I supply their indices directly, instead of `c`, and get them using `tf.gather(L,indices)`